# Determinant of $I + LL^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be symmetric positive definite. Given its eigendecomposition $$A=Q\Lambda Q^T$$ it's easy compute the determinant of $I + A$ as

$$I + A= QQ^T +Q\Lambda Q^T = Q(I+\Lambda)Q^T$$which is similar to $$I+A = \text{diag}(1+\lambda_1 ,\dots,1+\lambda_n)$$
Then the determinant is $$\vert I + A \vert= \prod_k (1+\lambda_k)$$

Now, suppose that instead of the eigendecomposition of $A$, we are given the Cholesky factorization $$A=LL^T$$

**Is there still a computationally efficient ($O(n)$) method for calculating $\vert I + LL^T \vert$?**

Comment: You could use the matrix determinant lemma to compute it from the determinant of $A$.

Comment: @DanielBeale wouldn't that be expensive as $I$ isn't a low-rank outer-product?

Comment: You would need to do $M$ updates with each standard basis vector. It would be a bit cheaper than doing the full Cholesky on $A+I$. You could also do rank one Cholesky updates with a similar complexity.

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping for something nicer as the eigendecomposition method is $O(n)$ rather than $O(n^2)$...